# Where can I find the "math, strings, etc... libraries" for Swift?

Tags: ios, cocoa, swift

I am looking at the Swift documentation, but I can't find reference to what there's in other languages...

Examples: `sin()`, `cos()`, `abs()` for math, `uppercase()`, `lowercase()` for strings, `sort()`, `pop()`, `push()` for arrays etc...

For strings I've found this [in the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH7-XID_368):

> Swift’s String type is bridged seamlessly to Foundation’s NSString
>   class. If you are working with the Foundation framework in Cocoa or
>   Cocoa Touch, the entire NSString API is available to call on any
>   String value you create, in addition to the String features described
>   in this chapter. You can also use a String value with any API that
>   requires an NSString instance.

Could you point me to some doc or where can I find those functions listed?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Looks like this is working...

```
import Foundation
var theCosOfZero: Double = Double(cos(0))  // theCosOfZero equals 1
```

Comment: let theCosOfZero = Double(cos(0.0))  // theCosOfZero equals 1                   No need for the import, I find. Ambiguity complaint, unless 0.0 is used.

Answer (score 10):

`sin()`, `cos()`, `abs()` are C methods defined in math.h https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/math.3.html

`"str".uppercaseString()` and `"str".lowercaseString()` are NSString methods.

`sort()` is part of the Swift Standard Library, documented at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688499-sort

`Array.append()` and `Array.removeLast()` are also defined in the Swift Standard Library, documented at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array

Comment: Ok for the ones in the Swift standard library, but for math.h why should I require a C library when almost every language has its own?

Comment: P.s. Can you provide an example of usage of sin() in a Swift playground? Thanks!

Comment: @Napolux you don't need to do anything to get access to math functions, just type sin(1.0) in XCode (or I assume the Swift playground, although I have not used that yet). The reason a C library is used internally is because Swift uses the same foundational libraries as ObjC (Apple presumably has no interest in maintaining two separate foundational libraries).

Comment: `uppercaseString()` is actually part of the swift standard library - [see reference docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/iOS/documentation/General/Reference/SwiftStandardLibraryReference/index.html)

Comment: @jhurliman: it's not true that "you don't need to do anything to get access to math functions". You need to `import Darwin`, or import something (e.g. Foundation) that imports Darwin.

Answer (score 10):

The math functions are defined in the **Darwin** module, so as absolute minimum you have add this:

```
import Darwin
```

In most cases `import Foundation` or `import Cocoa` will suffice, since those modules import the `Darwin` module. If you need access to constants like `M_PI` or similar, navigate with cmd+click to the `Darwin` module and the to the `Darwin.C`. Here you would find the C API imports and the `Darwin.C.math` among them. This way you may examine what's available, already converted to Swift. Nevertheless, all that C API is available with `import Darwin`.

You cannot issue `import Darwin.C.math` directly, because you will see the following runtime error (or similar if you're not in the playground):

```
Playground execution failed: Error in auto-import:
failed to get module 'math' from AST context
```

Example playground code:

```
import Darwin

func degToRad(degrees: Double) -> Double {
    // M_PI is defined in Darwin.C.math
    return M_PI * 2.0 * degrees / 360.0
}

for deg in 0..<360 {
    sin(degToRad(Double(deg)))
}
```

Comment: Where is the documentation of the Darwin module?

Comment: This is a far stretch form documentation for Darwin, but here is a blog post that has some very basic info. Sounds like it's an interface for the C standard Lib http://en.swifter.tips/asmname/